# Enable High Replication Datastore - Maven GWT + GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I'm trying to make High replication work with my application but I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications
```

Its likely that my maven plugins does not get the right configuration (`jvmFlag`):

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gaeVersion}</version>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <!-- gwt:compile happens just before package phase -->
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
           <modules>
              <module>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.App</module>
           </modules>
           <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
           <appEngineVersion>${gaeVersion}</appEngineVersion>
           <!-- tell the gwt plugin that the webapp source resides in src/main/webapp -->
           <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
           <!-- tell the gwt plugin that dev mode should be run using the webapp that resides in target/${webappDirectory} -->
           <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
           <!-- Normally the gwt maven plugin executes dev mode using a builtin jetty server.
                This config property instructs the gwt maven plugin to execute dev mode using the 
                jetty server supplied by the appengine sdk. -->
           <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
           <jvmFlags>
                <jvmFlag>-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20</jvmFlag>
           </jvmFlags>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

I run my application with this command `mvn gwt:run` it works fine, it can access the Datastore properly only that when doing `Transaction` I get that error. I have already added the jvmFlag but still it seems that it does not run the Datastore with High Replication.

I'm using GAE SDK version 1.7.5 BTW.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                        <appEngineVersion>1.8.0</appEngineVersion>
                        <runTarget>test.html</runTarget>
                        <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20</extraJvmArgs>
                    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This part of my POM works for me! I used `<extraJvmArgs>` instead of `<jvmFlag>`